# app.js is not created by Alloy. [Could not find the file app.js] error

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

My problem is

1. Run application on appcelerator studio.
2. Open /build/iphone folder with x code
3. Run in my device.

it shows error.

```
Could not find the file app.js
```

If I choose iphone simulator at step 3.It works fine.

This error happens only in real device.

My environments are

- SDK 5.1.1GA / 5.0.2GA tried both.
- alloy - v 1.7.30

What I have done is...

- ProjectA -> Make new project try same procedure. -> it works.
- ProjectB -> Make new project and copy some js sources from old project.(it means tiapp.xml and GUID is renewed). -> it shows error.

First, I compared two projects

```
ProjectA/Resources/app.js 
ProjectB/Resources/app.js
```

Both are created however, projectB's app.js is 0byte.

Second, I compared the both  /build/iphone/ folder

There is Asset folder in Xcode project, it has app_js file in projectA not in projectB.

These two results must be a hint though, I have no clue yet.

Does anyone help me?

---

Thanks to @Brenton.

I tried

```
ti clean && ti build -p ios --log-level trace
```

then put the log file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1320870/terminal%20output.txt).

I found sentences like though, can't find likely error.

```
[INFO]  [app.js] Titanium entry point processing...
[TRACE] - Processing "builtins" module...
[TRACE] - Processing "optimizer" module...
[TRACE] - Processing "compress" module...
[INFO]    created:    "Resources/iphone/app.js"
[DEBUG]   map:        "build/map/Resources/iphone/app.js.map"
[INFO]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is currently not possible to build from Xcode:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19818

There's a workaround in the above ticket.

In most cases you should not need to build from Xcode and just deploy to devices straight from the (AppC) Ti CLI.

Comment: Thanks @Fokke, I will try workaround(copy necessary resource from debug ipa to release build) way written that article.

Comment: Finally I use  'ti build --p ios -T device' , it works irrelevant with xcode

Comment: Ah yes, you were doing a Simulator build and then tried to run that on a device using Xcode? That might indeed not work because it will break over the symlinks. Not sure though. Glad it works now. Or do you mean that with `ti build -p ios -T device` it deploys to device fine *without* using Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, it is a result of a syntax error in the code from projectB.  Can you try building projectB from the terminal using:

```
ti clean && ti build -p ios --log-level trace
```

You should be able to see if there are any javascript syntax errors in the output log.

If this doesn't work, reply here and I can probably help you try a couple of other things.

Comment: Thanks very much @Brenton. I have tried your suggestion but can't find the clue yet. I put the log file in the main article.